# What does the h alias mean in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to ask if anyone is familiar with the "h" command on the smarty code?

```
<input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<!--{$category_id|h}-->" />
```

What does the h function mean?

Comment: I suspect it's a custom modifier in your install.  Check your plugins directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `h` does not seem to be part of Smarty's standard modifiers or functions. When you navigate to the smarty directory of your project, locate the "plugins" directory and search for a file "modifier.h.php" or "function.h.php" and have a look inside to find out what it does. Smarty comes along with a couple of modifiers and functions, but you are free to add your own, and I guess someone else (if not you) who is working on the same project added this file.

Comment: @Nap and when you find him, slap him for naming the function "h"